# What's the best configuration pattern when building a Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently building a Ruby gem and the configuration call needs to be validated.
My requirements are:

- default values
- validation for required
- validation for inclusion in a list of values

My first approach was as follows:

**configuration.rb**

```
module Configuration
  def define_setting(name, default: nil)
    class_variable_set("@@#{name}", default)

    define_singleton_method(name) do
      class_variable_get("@@#{name}")
    end

    define_singleton_method("#{name}=") do |value|
      class_variable_set("@@#{name}", value)
    end
  end
end
```

**gem.rb**

```
module Gem
  extend Configuration

  define_setting :api_url, default: DEFAULT_API_URL
end
```

**gem_initializer.rb**

```
Gem.configuration do |c|
  c.api_url = ENV['DEFAULT_API_URL']
end
```

I removed the code to validate inclusion, but that's quite straightforward. The issue is trying to validate required values. I could basically add a `required: true` argument to the `define_setting` method, save it in an array, and check if the `configuration` call sets all the required values. I find this a little bit too complicated.

Another approach would be to move all the configuration logic inside the `Configuration` module, create an initializer method and check if the `api_url` gets passed.

```
class Configuration
  attr_accessor :api_url

  def initialize(api_url)
    @api_url = api_url

    message = "Configuration value 'api_url' is required."
    raise StandardError, message if @api_url.to_s.empty?
  end
end
```

and the initializer would look something like:

```
Gem::Configuration.new(api_url: ENV['DEFAULT_API_URL'])
```

Hope my explanation makes sense. Does anybody have an idea on what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: I might not be understanding the problem fully, but an easy out might be using 'fetch', which checks if things (especially environment variables) are set. So if you set the initializer as `Gem::Configuration.new(api_url: ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_API_URL'))`, it would raise an exception if you're missing the environment variable.

Comment: Using environment variables is recommended, but theres nothing stopping the user putting a String instead, then the `fetch` check would get ignored.